# Proving that dim ImT ≤ dim V without using nullity

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let T : V → W be a linear transformation.
Prove dim ImT ≤ dim V (without using dimKerT + dimImT = n).

I thought about using the fact that V=Span{v1,...,vn} and ImT=Span{T(v1),...,T(vn)}, and then claim that if {v1,...,vn} is linearly independent then dimImT=dim(n), and if it's linearly dependent then there is at least one vector that can be removed, so dimImT <= dim(n).
But I'm not really sure how to formalize it.

Comment: What is the maximum possible dimension of a vector space spanned by $n$ vectors...?

Comment: @CameronWilliams But theoretically it is possible that dimV<n and dimV<=dimImT<=n, isn't it? (As long as I haven't proven it is not possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any linear map can be viewed as matrix product.

If $T: V \to W$ is linear then $T(v)$ can be viewed as $Av$ for $A \in \Re^{dim(W) \times dim(V)}$.

The dimention of image of $T$ is the same as the dimention of the column space of $A$, $img(T)=dim(colum(A))$.

The column space of $A$ has dimension at most the number of columns in $A$ which is $dim(V)$.

Therefore, $dim(img(T))$ is at most $dim(V)$.